# Google map does not show inside bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

My map appears blank inside the bootstrap modal. The popular answer to this problem is to trigger the resize event of the map object inside the bootstrap shown event. My code is this

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
        switch (e.target.hash) {
            .
            .
            .
            case "#mapTab":
                $("#mapTab").show();
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(latLng);
```

by the time this happens I got the map and latLng objects initialised, in order to use them in the event handler. however the map still is not showing. Any other ideas? and my html is below

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist" id="ucPills">
        .
        . 
        .
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#mapTab" aria-controls="mapTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><%= Resources.ConsumptionUnit.Map %></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="mapTab">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="smallmap"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be due to the **CSS** . You might have forgot to change the selector in the CSS:

```
#map {
 height: 400px;
 width: 500px;
}
```

OR

Try to trigger the resize in the callback of `show()`:

```
$("#mapTab").show('fast', function() { //You can replace "fast" with any other effect or time.
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(latLng);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had trouble implementing this. First I had this code at the same level as the bootstrap shown event and was getting an undefined error. I then moved it into where the map is initialized, the error was gone but my display got affected as now the mapTab div got a display of block. The map however still hidden.

Comment: @KonstantinosPapakonstantinou Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: I just did, but the problem is that on the fiddle it works...https://jsfiddle.net/Lnub789o/4/

Comment: Maybe you have the CSS wrong somewhere. Can you check the CSS too and share it here?

Comment: It was the CSS.......it didnt like setting its dimensions to 100%. If you want you can post an answer and I shall accept it....thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @KonstantinosPapakonstantinou Okay, Updated